# Full Calendar static eventSources

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar eventSources to pull json event data from server. I have a variable `sheet_id` that changes and the `selected_sheet_id()` function will return the corresponding sheet selected. The problem is that when I call `$("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents')` to return events, `sheet_id` (thus all the events) are always the same. That is fullcalendar does not get refreshed with the current `sheet_id` before fetching events. How do I trigger the eventSources to "recompile" so that it pulls the correct `sheet_id` from the function before executing ajax call.

```
eventSources: [{
    url: '/event/get_events',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        sheet_id: selected_sheet_id()
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
    }     
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

First Try this with `async:false`  for sync call :

```
eventSources: [
          {
           url: '/event/get_events',
           type: 'GET',
           async:false,
           data:{
                  sheet_id: selected_sheet_id()
                },
           error: function() {
              alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
              },      
          },
             ]
```

Otherwise made one method which fetch  event data in using `Ajax call` For ex :

```
  var ajaxreturnstring="";
       $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "/EMR-PHR/getPatientScheduleajax.html", 
           dataType:"html",
            data: "",
           async:false,
            success: function(data){
                ajaxreturnstring=$.trim(data);
                 var obj = eval("("+txt+")");
                     return obj;
            },  
            error: function(e){  
              alert('Error: ' + e);  
            }  
          }); 


   }
```

Comment: I tried async:false and that does not work. I could write a separate ajax request but I wanted to use fullcalendar's calling methods as they have the proper triggers when to make call to get events when day,month, year is switched. Full calendar update call methods also provide the correct date frame to search for as well.

Comment: you can first find function with call every time on day,month, year is switched.  And than do Ajax call from that function . So every time you get updated JSON object I have done same in my jquery week calender plugin.

Comment: I original tried that, linking the different buttons to an update AJAX call but the problem was that the AJAX update call would fire before full calendar could update the variable showing what month was being viewed. Thus I had to send all event data one month before and after the reported month being viewed from full calendar. (This way I would have all data for the dates that could be viewed) This was wasteful in my opinion which is why I looked into using fullcalendars methods that pull from a specified url and actually give the current updated dates being viewed.